# Summarize all possible combinations in pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have table which represents sequence of points, I need to get sum by all possible combinations. The main problem is how to do it with minimum actions because the Real table is huge

| Col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | ct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | id5 | id6 | 30 |
| Id8 | id3 | id5 | id2 | id4 | id6 | 45 |

The expected result is:

| p1 | p2 | ct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id3 | id5 | 75 |
| Id3 | id4 | 75 |
| Id3 | id6 | 75 |
| Id5 | id6 | 75 |
| Id2 | id4 | 75 |
| Id2 | id6 | 75 |
| Id4 | id6 | 75 |

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Do you really need all the combinations of columns? all combinations of rows would be much much efficient and keep the same information. What are you doing with this?

Comment: This table is a sequence of waypoints.
In other words, I don't need all possible combinations, but only combinations in order from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly you want the following:

For each combination of elements from the two rows, the result should have a row with the two elements and the sum of the `ct` column.

Unfortunately, *all combinations* is not something that can be done very efficiently. Pandas has no built-in functionality for this, but the `itertools` package in the standard library has the `product` function, which does what you want:

```py
from itertools import product

a = ["id1", "id2"]
b = ["id3", "id4"]

for combination in product(a, b):
    print(combination)
```

This gives

```py
('id1', 'id3')
('id1', 'id4')
('id2', 'id3')
('id2', 'id4')
```

Applying this to your data:

```py
combinations = product(*[df.loc[i, df.columns != "ct"] for i in df.index])

result = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["p1", "p2", "ct"])

for i, combination in enumerate(combinations):
    the_sum = df["ct"].sum()
    result.loc[i] = [*combination, the_sum]
```

The magic here is in the first line, which takes each row in your dataframe, ignoring the "ct" column, and calculates all possible combinations with one item from each row.

However, I don't think I quite understand what you're trying to achieve; do you only have two rows? And how exactly should the sum be calculated? In the example you give it's always the same number, is that correct?

Comment: This table is a sequence of waypoints.
In other words, I don't need all possible combinations, but only combinations in order from left to right.
The task is to find segments from which an intermediate point can be removed, based on a sufficient number of ct.
The sum is correct because ther are only two rows in this example.
With more lines the situation will change